# SE doesn't identify Android tablets correctly

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, mobile-web

I'm using a Nexus 10 tablet and I was surprised that SE serves me the mobile version of the site by default. The full version is much more useful on a tablet, with exception of chat which has some issues on tablets.

My user agent is 'Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 4.2.1; Nexus 10 Build/JOP40D) AppleWebKit/535.19 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/18.0.1025.166 Safari/535.19'

The official way of distinguishing an Android tablet and a phone is to watch for the "mobile" part in the user agent (https://developers.google.com/chrome/mobile/docs/user-agent). Not every single Android tablet follows this convention, but it seems to be the official guideline from Google.

From the [Google Webmaster blog](http://googlewebmastercentral.blogspot.de/2012/11/giving-tablet-users-full-sized-web.html):

> Tablets offer a browsing experience that can be as rich as any desktop
>   or laptop machine, in a more mobile, lightweight, and generally more
>   convenient package. **This means that, unless you offer
>   tablet-optimized content, users expect to see your desktop site rather
>   than your site’s smartphone site.**
>
> [...]
>
> For Android-based devices, it’s easy to distinguish between
>   smartphones and tablets using the user-agent string supplied by
>   browsers: Although both Android smartphones and tablets will include
>   the word “Android” in the user-agent string, only the user-agent of
>   smartphones will include the word “Mobile”.

Please change the user agent detection so that tablets following the Google recommendations are recognized properly.

Additional sources for distinguishing Android phones and tablets:

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/5344382/347857
- http://googlewebmastercentral.blogspot.de/2011/03/mo-better-to-also-detect-mobile-user.html
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Gecko_user_agent_string_reference

Answer (score 4, accepted):

And so the check for "is a tablet" grows increasingly complex.

This will go out with the next build.