# stackoverflow.com serves desktop version to Opera Mini on Android 2.3

Tags: bug, status-completed, mobile-web, android, opera-mini

Starting yesterday afternoon (i.e. 05/12/2012 at about 16:00 CET) stackoverflow.com started serving the desktop version of the site to my handheld using Opera Mini on Android 2.3. (whereas it used to serve the mobile site before).

I am not sure if this is happening by design, yet I think that about 99% of Opera Mini users would agree with me when I say that I would *strongly* prefer getting the mobile version as both the layout and functionality of the full version of SO is complete overkill for a tool as simple as Opera Mini.

Is this a bug or does this change have any background?

**EDIT**:
UA String is `Opera/9.80 (Android; Opera Mini/6.5.27452/28.3234; U; de) Presto/2.8.119 Version/11.10`

Comment: I probably caused this by [asking for Android tablets to be identified as tablets and served the full version](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/157485/se-doesnt-identify-android-tablets-correctly), which was implemented yesterday. Can you post your user agent here? Your phone is probably omitting the "mobile" identifier it is supposed to send.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's really rather frustrating how inconsistent browsers on Android tablets are, I doubt we'll ever be perfect.

That being said, the next build should fix this particular issue.

Comment: Wonderful, thanks a whole lot for fixing that and all the other great work on the site!!!